# Specialized template classes with common functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible to specialize a few functions for a template class without specializing the whole thing?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    int foo();
};

template <typename T>
int A<T>::foo() { return 1;}

template <>
struct A<int> {
    int bar() { return 2; };
};

main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.foo(); //1
    a.bar(); //2
    A<double> b;
    b.foo(); //1
    b.bar(); // ERROR
}
```

Or something similar?

Comment: Are you looking for explicit specializations only? If so, yes, it can be done([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff29848730f493f3)). However, you cannot partially specialize this way and have to jump through hoops.

Comment: No, the question was more along the lines of functions that are ONLY specializations.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment. Does the example I linked to cover all the cases you care about?

Comment: Notice that `A<int>` above defined the function `bar`.  But `bar` doesn't exist unless `T` is `int`.  This is allowed, however you have to declare TWO copies of `A` to do it, one with `bar` and `foo`, and one without `bar`... I was wondering if it was possible to not have that.

Comment: Ah I completely missed that the primary template didn't have `bar`. Yes, C++ classes aren't "open" like, say, Python classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But there is a way around it.

Hand off the logic to a free function template specialisation from within the template class method.

```
template<class T>
int delegated_foo() {
    return 1;
}

// now specialise 
template<>
int delegated_foo<int>() {
  return 2;
}

template <typename T>
struct A {
    int foo() {
        return delegated_foo<T>();
    }
};
```

To answer the comment - if you want to partially specialise a class, you can delegate common logic in to a template base class.

```
template<class T>
struct a_common {
  void common_function() { 
    // define here. Compiler will generate 1 for each T  
  }
};

template<class T>
struct A : public a_common<T>
{
  int something_i_might_specialise();
};
```

Comment: so if I want to have a template class that is specialized at all I have to copy the entire class?

Comment: yes, although if there is common logic you might want to put that into a template base class that does not need specialisation. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Wait: so you can't have specialization of ANY template class method without specializing ALL of the methods?

Comment: If you specialise a class you have to specialise the whole class. However the specialised class can be inherited from unspecialised classes.